# Can I ignore some type of errors using flow?

Tags: flowtype

I just want to either ignore some type of error, or specify a rule on it. in my case it is `Cannot resolve name` type error. Can I set global variables ? (outside calling code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with library definition files. For example:

1. Create a folder and call it something like `definitions`
2. Add this folder under the `[libs]` section in your `.flowconfig`
3. Create a file inside `definitions` and call it something like `globals.js`

Inside this `globals.js` file (or any file inside the `definitions` folder), you can write *declarations*. You can see the exact syntax for doing that here: https://flow.org/en/docs/libdefs/creation/

For example, if I wanted to declare that a global `age` variable exists, I would have this inside my `globals.js` file:

```
declare var age: number;
```

You can also declare complex objects:

```
declare type Person = {
  name: string,
  age: number
};

declare var person: Person;
```

If you don't know what type the global variable is, you can set it to `any`:

```
declare var weirdThing: any;
```

If the global variable is coming from a popular 3rd party library, there are probably library definitions that you can install to automatically get type information about it and stop flow errors. Check out [flow-typed](https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed) if you haven't already.

---

For reference:

Using the example I showed above, your folder structure would look something like:

```
.
├── .flowconfig
├── definitions
│   └── globals.js
├── package.json
└── src
```

and your `.flowconfig` contents would look something like:

```
[ignore]

[include]

[libs]
definitions

[lints]

[options]

[strict]
```

Comment: You'll want to use suppress comments. Check out the [docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/#toc-suppress-comment-regex) for them.

Comment: thank you. Is it possible to ignor a rule in the config in one place?

Comment: Couldn't you just use a suppress comment in that one place? Or am I misunderstanding your question? (It might be better for you to open a new question to go into more detail)

Comment: I think the new question will be duplicate of this one. I want to disable one rule in config. I don't want to use suppress comment everywhere.

Comment: Are you saying you want to disable that config rule in one file? Or do you just want to disable that config rule everywhere? And could you share which exact rule you're trying to disable just to get some context?

Comment: I want to disable a rule everywhere. I want to disable rule that forbid to use `Foo.defaultProps = {}` when Foo is class component. https://gist.github.com/StanislavMayorov/eaaa09555eb135d7f031c5fe2afe3ad3

Comment: I think you should be making it a static class member instead. https://flow.org/en/docs/react/components/#toc-using-default-props

Comment: We prefer this way the same as airbnb. https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/react#ordering 
So there is no way to disable except use comments everywhere?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. I don't think there is any way to disable a single type of Flow error, sorry!

Comment: However, it is possible to do it in that style as long as you declare the type in the class definition: [flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBLAtgBzgJwBcwAlAUwEMBjQgGjAG8BhOXOAOzPcIF8wp8rMAHJ8lGsIDc6QgE8cZMAAVBOAM5gAvIx7TUchWAAiZKBQCuMQirjqtjVGDAAjCvgBcYduazOy+VB50KhgKNQ0AMTg4MDIAD0IuABMNFjZObgAeG3UAPgcnNUIKQgwqMCTTCysctU8TM0trVTU9JzF2SvwACgBKAqcwMUJzfHYvSxhpJyCg1Ci4ADpKxpqW+wZHFzdPAEYABkC9eLwiCqqmsAXJIA).

Comment: Please visit this artcle, It will help you. https://wietse.loves.engineering/ignore-a-flowtype-error-on-a-specific-line-14cdfa70a739

Answer (score 0):

Placing `// $FlowFixMe` before the line in question, will suppress errors for Flow v0.33 or greater.